# Forms authentication with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr

I have gone through wiki on SignalR and still can't figure out how to do Forms authentication with SignalR. I'd like to invoke a call to a hub (or persistent connection) with username/password and be able to return a redirect to an authenticated page, along with setting forms authentication cookie.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do forms auth through SignalR. Do it outside of SignalR (as you would normally) and then you can check to make sure incoming calls, and subscribers to your hub are authenticated.

Comment: what if the client Javascript falls in the hands of an intruder? knowing the hub name wouldn't allow anyone to connect - unless I set up an authentication through signalR when connecting the hub - but in this case I should encrypt the password - is there anything native in SignalR so that we don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: SignalR is built on http so you use what security http provides. SignalR flows the IPrincipal to user code from the underlying host (ASP.NET or self host). 

I'm not sure what you mean by javascript falls into the hands of an intruder. Can you be more specific?

Comment: yep, sorry I was a bit confusing. If I understand properly, to connect for instance the hub via JS client you call the auto script `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`. I bet this is the node I should protect using Forms authentication, I don't have a clue how to do that though - since it is not a physical resource. I am sure I am missing something here but could not find any example...
An attacker who knows that the server is running signalR could try to set up a connection calling /signalr/hubs or, knowing the renamed hub /renHub/hubs - wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: I think it even more simple thinking of the SignalR.Client. If the home page of my site is not restricted, couldn't I set up a connection with HubConnection and start using the hub referencing the hub methods I could have read from a cached copy of a JS page (downloaded by a legit user)?

Comment: In the last comment I meant the .NET Client, sorry

Comment: You're worried about somebody downloading the javascript file? I'm not sure what you're trying to protect... I'll state again that SignalR uses http. Whatever auth/protection you normally use in ASP.NET (the host).

Comment: let me try again. Suppose I install SignalR as per QuickStart setup. Suppose the website should not allow any anonymous user to browse any page except the home page, and that I want that SignalR broadcast only to registered users. If I am an anonymous user, couldn't I still connect the SignalRHub simply using the SignalR .NET Client for instance?  To setup a connection I just have to create HubConnection -this will call the default hub for which I have no place where to specify the `Authorize` attribute (which would allow me to enforce security on the hub).

Comment: You would implement IConnected and write the following code in Connect

if(!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) throw new Exception("GTFO");

Comment: wow thanks, got that now. When you've got time, I think it would be valuable adding somewhere in the SignalR documentation - I bet it could help people like me able to drown in a glass of water :)

Comment: actually seems not be working fine - continuing in a new question at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157883/signalr-how-to-enforce-authentication-terminate-hub-connections-server-side)