# SignalR: how to enforce authentication/terminate hub connections server side

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr

This question is related to another thread, you can read [here: Forms authentication with SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488461/forms-authentication-with-signalr)  where I tried with the help and patience of the user [dfowler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45091/dfowler) to understand how enforce forms ASP .NET Forms Authentication on a SignalR Hub.

Description of the problem: I want that only authenticated users can connect the SignalR Hub and receive/send messages.

Intrusion scenario: the intruder can potentially capture/access the HTML and Javascripts of the web page accessing the temporary files on a client computer. This intruder can therefore know all the details (methods, hub names etc) required to set up/use a connection to the Hub.
A proposed solution from dfowler is [implementing IConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488461/forms-authentication-with-signalr/11519916#comment16235850_11519916):

> You would implement IConnected and write the following code in Connect if(!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) throw new Exception("GTFO");

Therefore I tried with something like this

```
  public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Connect()
    {
        if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            || !(Context.User.IsInRole("role1") || Context.User.IsInRole("role2")
            ))
            throw new Exception("User not authorized");
        return null;
    }
```

The problem, once tested, is that when the Connect method is being called, the connection has been already established and plain throwing the exception will not help (if I got if properly infact Connect should be used to send a message to the client at connection, throwing an exception will just yield in a *welcome message* not sent).

In facts, from my tests, the clients can still read all the messages (and also send them).

Now, approaches which come to my mind:

1. Perfect solution: reject or terminate the connection on server side: **no clue how to do this in SignalR** (I tried to find a method in the [API](http://signalr.net/docs/api/v0.5.1/SignalR.Hubs/Hub.htm) but no luck)
2. check if the user is part of a group to avoid receiving/sending messages to him (but this is still prone to flooding/DOS attacks)
3. Sending a message to the client to disconnect: obviously does not help in case I am fighting an intruder.

Any other approach? Any way to terminate the connection on server side or should be accepted that the only real authentication is the one of the host webpage (leaving open the door to all the signalR client attacks?)

**EDIT**

Here is the sequence of client - server communication when I use the `IConnect.Connect` method throwing unconditionally an exception (browser IE9):

[image: client-server communication when Connect throws exception]

It looks like the foreverFrame fails but the longPolling fallback is being established and works anyway - this after throwing the error captured in the Javascript by the block

```
 if (connection.state === signalR.connectionState.connecting) {
            // Connection hasn't been started yet
            throw "SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. 
    Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after 
    the connection has started.";
        }
```

Comment: [feature request](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/635) created in the SignalR GitHub Project site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an issue where we need to allow blocking the connection altogether. Right now you'll have to guard each method. It's not the cleanest but for 1.0 alpha1 we'll have some mechanism for doing this.

One additional problem is that it's the same connection for all hubs so you can't reject a connection for a specific hub.

**EDIT**

Actually if you throw it does end the connection as far as my testing goes. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Understood now - obviously things are more complicated than a first thought, as usual. However this is a major problem as it makes SignalR not fit for corporate applications and opens a big threat in terms of security - pls give some priority to this... 
About the auto-reconnect, I have added some details in the question itself - sorry for being such a pain, dfowler :)

Comment: my twopence - to connect the Hub, the client has to get `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`. Wouldn't it be possible to make the server side of this go through ASP.NET authentication? Not sure if this approach can be extended to the SignalR.Client, too...

Comment: That's not true. That's a generated proxy for convenience, has nothing to do with the fact that you can connect to a hub or not. The only thing we need to add (and we will) is a clean way to reject connections completely, based on some user defined logic. Authentication never happens inside of SignalR itself. But you get to check and verify in SignalR.

If you really needed to get this to work today, you could write an ASP.NET module and short circuited requests to signalr altogether but that's painful.

Comment: @davidfowl Any news about this issue?